# What does r10k provide since Puppet natively supports directory environments?

Tags: puppet, r10k

I'm just starting to read about r10k because I love the fact that it can create dynamic environments based on Git branches. Now, I just read that Puppet can do this without r10k. What does r10k provide that Puppet cannot already do? If I just want the dynamic directory-based environments based on Git branches, do I even need r10k?

Comment: What is [r10k](http://www.r10k.org/R10K/About_R10K.html)?

Comment: [Puppet does not do the same thing.](https://github.com/adrienthebo/r10k/blob/master/doc/dynamic-environments/introduction.mkd)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

R10k deploys modules into the environment you tell it to. Those modules could come from the Forge, or a git repository. That functionality is not available in Puppet.

The ways to use it are legion, but personally I tend to do something like [this](http://www.chriscowley.me.uk/blog/2014/06/25/super-slick-agile-puppet-for-devops/).